Does Hulk's Radioactive Lockdown protect enemies from allied debuffs?
The description for Hulk's Radioactive Lockdown ability says:

Emit gamma energy to place enemies in a quantum void that renders them immobilized and immune to all ability effects.

I assume this means an enemy hit with Radioactive Lockdown can't receive positive buffs from abilities. Does it also mean that an enemy will be temporarily immune to debuffs from your allies attacking them?
